# A require a server hosting package that would be suitable for several .net managed applications, accessed only by me

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, hosting, .net, shared-hosting

I currently run a server at home consisting of

- SQL Server 2008
- .net Framework 2010
- VPN Connection
- ASP.net Web Services

running around 5-6 applications supporting a financial trading system that i regularly use. THe only user is me.
Recently the requirement to have these applications running in a 24/7 100% uptime (or 99%) environment has become important. No longer can I both meet this requirement and host my server at home on my network - so i am looking to move to a dedicated hosting company.

After some research, the only real companies I can find offering such services are geared towards company web-space hosting. I don't need 1TB+ bandwidth, what i need is CPU, Memory and as much control over the environment as possible.

Does anyone have any examples of such a service?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy a server. Put it in a hosting center.  This is called colocation.